# Ethereum Miner validation

Tags: transactions, mining, accounts, balances

I have created a private block chain with three Peers. Peer A is having an account which is having 20 ether. Now I am trying send 21 ether from peer A's account to peer B's Account. It is not throwing any error in geth console even though Account is having less ether.

I have used below command for sending ether:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:"0x871fDd8F5896fA9a8D1389F498cc05e0752cA4fE",to:"0x9B5AC566B9c35388a27B098FA8a3407b1f81324C", value: 21})
```

Comment: Do any peer on the network is mining? and what return you are getting after mentioned operation?

Comment: it is providing this below hash code

Comment: use eth.getTransaction(TxHash) to see the info of transaction

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the participant has to be a miner (See how to start and stop a miner) for your Txs to be confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

If the account does not have enough balance, the transaction will fail. Prior to that, there will be no prevention.